# Passing data from database-populated checkboxes to PHP via jquery

Tags: php, jquery, database, checkbox

I have a set of merchant options in a search function that I have created by using php/mysql to populate them from the database.

```
<div class="options_list">
    <?php 
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT MerchantName FROM `TABLE 1` ");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    echo '<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox_searchoptions" id="' . $row["MerchantName"] . '" value="' . $row["MerchantName"] . '"/><label for="' . $row["MerchantName"] . '">' . $row["MerchantName"] . '</label>';
    }
    ?>
</div><!--end of options_list-->
```

(haven't updated the old code to mysqli yet)

These are jquery UI styled checkboxes. I cannot get my head around how to identify each individual checkbox to pass to jquery or php.

An example of one of my other search options is below:
It has jquery like this:

```
$("#checkblack").button();
$("#checkblack").on("click", function () {
    search ();
});
```

The search() function is something like below:

```
    var wblack = $("#checkblack:checked").val();
    if (wblack) {
        ajax_data.wblack = wblack;
    }
```

And this data is passed to php via ajax.

The php is:

```
$where = array ();
if (isset($_GET['wblack'])) {
$where[] = 'ProductDescription LIKE "%' . addslashes  ($_GET['wblack']) . '%"';
}
```

Then a mysql query is passed to get the results.

How would I go about distinguishing each individual merchant so that I can pass one or more of these options, when they are checked, via ajax to the php mysql query? My issue is that I have been using IDs with the other options to identify them in jquery however as the merchant options have been echoed from a database I do not seem to be able to do them the same way. I hope I have made this clear enough! Thanks.

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're using `addslashes` you're already going down the wrong path. `mysql_query` is an obsolete interface and should not be used in new applications as it's being removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). If you're new to PHP, a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices.

Comment: Yeah, I realise it is antiquated now. I will be modernising it before the site goes 'live'. However this was just an example to show the problem I'm having re the database populated checkboxes and getting their individual values. Also, thanks for the PHP guide that'll come in handy

Comment: Good to know. It's usually best to avoid digging too deep a hole with `mysql_query` because the probability that laziness will set in and you'll just ship it because it's "working" increases. From there leads to misery and suffering if you've left a vulnerability.

Comment: I think there was a possibilty of that happening! I'm going to make sure its updated and airtight once I have sorted out some of my tinkering issues